# How to remove specific content form strings on odd index lines in text file

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm trying to replace for specific content in strings located only on the odd index number lines inside text document about 30 000 rows, and avoid it for even lines content. For example with index numbers just to see:

```
0. some text a2 
1. a1 some text a3 
2. some a3 text
3. some text a3
4. some a4 text
```

I want use list for string values which must be removed:

```
var valueList1 = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" };
```

But I'm not sure how to get line by index to replace it this way

```
if (index % 2 == 0)  
{
   string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
          text = text.Replace("a1", "")
                     .Replace("a2", "")
                     .Replace("a3", "")
                     .Replace("a4", "");
   File.WriteAllText(path, text);  
}
```

to get this result in text document:

```
some text a2 
some text 
some a3 text
some text  
some a4 text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
int cnti = 0;
var ignoreList = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" };
string outputstring = string.Empty;
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("some.txt"))
{
    if(cnti % 2 == 0)
        outputstring += line;
    else
        outputstring += string.Join(" ", line.Split().Where(w => !ignoreList.Contains(w)));

    outputstring += Environment.NewLine;
    cnti++;
}
File.WriteAllText("some.txt", outputstring);
```

Reading the lines one by one and also used a variable (cnti) to count the lines we read. When the `(cnti % 2 == 0)` then we should leave the line as it is and in else part we should remove the strings from the array in `ignoreList`

Comment: Hello, yes works well,   if I want for example remove specific  duplicated strings with odd index in this code? Anyway thank you, work as I asked

Comment: You can ask another question for the same like what duplicate and what has to be removed with desired output would be easier to answer. @nikorio.